# How can I reuse a Transformer with inverse_transform in a scikit-learn Pipeline

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I'm trying to make a scikit-learn Pipeline with the endgoal of compressing my data. I am using mostly custom transformers. To explain my Problem I will be using sklearn.decomposition.PCA, as it is very close to how my own transformer works.

For the next steps in my Pipeline I do not need the actual values of the `pca.transform()`, but rather of `pca.inverse_transform(pca.transform())`. However, I need access to the result of the transform method in another step, so I can't use `transform()` to `transform()` and instantly `inverse_transform()`.

Minimum working example:

```
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

class CustomPCA(PCA):
    def __init__(self, inverse=False, n_components=None):
        super().__init__(n_components=n_components)
        self.inverse = inverse

    def fit(self, X, y=None):
        if self.inverse:
            super().fit(X[1], y)  # use original data
        else:
            super().fit(X, y)
        return self
        
    def transform(self, X):
        if self.inverse:
            return super().inverse_transform(X[0])  # use transformed data
        transformed = super().transform(X)
        return (transformed, X)  # return transformed and untransformed data
        
    def fit_transform(self, X, y=None):
        return self.fit(X).transform(X)
        
pipe = Pipeline([("pca", CustomPCA(n_components=3)),
                 ("inv", CustomPCA(inverse=True, n_components=3))])
X = np.random.uniform(0,5,(100,10))+np.arange(10)
plt.plot(X.T)
plt.show()
plt.plot(pipe.fit_transform(X).T)
plt.show()
```

[Original Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ydxnq.png)

[Transformed and Retransformed Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EhBrL.png)

While this does work I think it is rather clunky. Is there a way I can reuse a transformer, while using the `inverse_transform()` method instead `of transform()`?